# Find 3d rotation matrix of a plane from a 2d image

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to determine the rotation matrix of a plane in the 3d space from a 2d image where the positions of the corners and the width/height ratio of the plane are known in the 2d space.

Let's say the blue lines represent a 2d plane in the 3d space. The `width * height` of the plane in the 2d space = `8 * 6`. The pivot in this case is `(0,0)`. The other corners of the blue lines are known as 2d vectors relative to the pivot, in this case `[(6,4), (10,-.5), (8,-5)]`. The red lines represent the "original" plane.

[image]

How would I calculate this? I'm not interested in a specific answer (the actual rotation matrix) for this case, but rather the steps that have to be taken to get there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this image the result of a standard pinhole camera projection?

Comment: @Hyperion The transformation that maps the red rectangle onto the blue quadrilateral can’t be linear (or even affine) because the rectangle’s image isn’t a parallelogram. At any rate, the OP is basically looking for the rotation that maps 3-D world coordinates to camera coordinates.

Comment: @amd Yes exactly. I don't have the 3d-world coordinates, but I do have the 2d-measurements and 2d points in space.

Comment: The short answer is that you don’t have enough information to even recover the rotation part of the camera’s pose from a single image. Even assuming square pixels, no skew and the principal point at the image coordinate origin, the solutions to the resulting equations have two degrees of freedom.

Comment: I have the camera intrinsics, distortion coefficients and reprojection error available. Is that enough or do I need something else as well?

Comment: You need to tell us what those are and what they mean. Without knowing how the rectangle is projected onto the plane, it's not possible to proceed.

Comment: @amd My bad I thought it was

Comment: BTW, in your illustration, the source rectangle is $9\times6$, not $8\times6$.